# How can I sort a list for sentence alphabetically in python based on 2nd or 3rd word or something like that

Tags: python, sorting

How can I sort a list for sentence alphabetically in python based on **2nd or 3rd** word or something like that.

**Example:**

```
Input: ["The efgh ijk", "The abcd efgh", "The aab xyz"]
Output: ["The aab xyz", "The abcd efgh", "The efgh ijk"]
```

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where a string within the list contains more or less than 3 words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base title of your question : `Sorting based on 2nd or 3rd word`

You can use `sorted` with `lambda` and `split()` like below:

*(this approach first consider 2nd word then 3rd word)*

```
>>> lst = ["The efgh ijk" ,"The aab wxy", "The abcd efgh", "The aab xyz"]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda item: (item.split()[1], item.split()[2]))
['The aab wxy', 'The aab xyz', 'The abcd efgh', 'The efgh ijk']


>>> lst = ["The efgh ijk" ,"The aab wxy", "The abcd efgh", "The aab xyz", "abc efgh xyz"]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda item: (item.split()[1], item.split()))
['The aab wxy', 'The aab xyz', 'The abcd efgh', 'The efgh ijk', 'abc efgh xyz']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain in detail which logic is behind this, or how actually this sorting works?

Comment: @TanvirAhmmed welcome, You ask sort base 2nd and 3rd, then first you need to split word, `The efgh ijk`.split() -> `The, efgh, ijk` then you can use `soretd`  function, in this function you can say base each key you want to sort. for this purpose, you can use `str.split()` and send 2nd , 3rd word`

Answer (score 1):

lst = ["The efgh ijk", "The abcd efgh", "The aab xyz"]

sort_lst = sorted(lst)

print(sort_lst)